# Access the most parent controller from child component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-components, angular1.6

I'm using angular 1.5 components in my application and here is my structure:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="appController as app">
    <div ui-view="home">
        <home-component>
            {{ app.user }}
        </home-component>
    </div>
</body>
```

Basically, I am using the ui-router for nested views together with Angular components.

I know that, using the `controller as` syntax, you can access the parent controller, however for some reason I cannot. Nothing is being displayed for `{{ app.user }}`

Now I have read, the the scope of a component is isolated, but I thought that simply means that parent components can't access child components.

If it is fully isolated, how would I go about accessing global data in parent controller?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`require` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) to access a parent controller and map
a binding to the controller of the child component:

```
app.component("homeComponent", {
  require: {main: "^ngController"},
  template: 
    `<fieldset>
      <h3>home-component</h3>
      <p> $ctrl.main.user = {{$ctrl.main.user}}</p>
    </fieldSet>`
})
```

The above example binds to the controller of the [ng-controller directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

From the Docs:

> Intercomponent Communication
>
> Directives can [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) the controllers of other directives to enable communication between each other. This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Components (Intercomponent Communication)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/h5C3lh9MWhvy9qF0Amvx?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component("homeComponent", {
  require: {main: "^ngController"},
  template: 
    `<fieldset>
      <h3>home-component</h3>
      <p> $ctrl.main.user = {{$ctrl.main.user}}</p>
    </fieldSet>`
})
.controller("appController", function() {
  var main = this;
  main.user = "someUser";
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController as main">
      <h2>Main App</h2>
      <input ng-model="main.user" />
      <br><br>
      <home-component>
      </home-component>
  </body>
```

Comment: I ended up using your answer because I have the ng-controller to reference! It worked great thank You! But I imagine the @Mike FeltMan answer also works. The only difference is one references controller and the other one references a component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use requires to create a reference to it in the child component.

This syntax will basically everywhere to find it:

```
require: {
      app: '^homeComponent'
    }
```

Or this syntax will just look up one for the component as a parent:

```
require: {
      app: '^^homeComponent'
    }
```

Then in the child component you can reference the homeComponent via the app property.

You can also make the reference optional by prefacing it with a ? like:

```
  app: '?^^homeComponent'
```

Comment: Thank You so much! I ended up going with what @georgeawg had, mainly because his referencing the controller itself instead of a component. But imagine, this works great for referencing the parent component. For some reason, I always thought it would look one level up, but apparently it looks for all levels above it.

Answer (score 0):

If a directive is isolated, it is best passing whatever values you need to use by parameters, else why making it isolated?

```
<home-component user="app.user"></home-component>

.directive('homeComponent', function() {
  return {
    scope: { user: '=' },
    ...
  }
})
```

Or you can transclude the content if it is not needed for use inside the child directive

```
<home-component>
    {{ app.user }}
</home-component>

.directive('homeComponent', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Components are a slightly different animal than directives and have specific features designed to deal with what the OP asked about. Since Angular 1.5 components are preferable to directives for DOM creation in most scenarios.

Comment: @MikeFeltman Thanks for telling about components, didn't know they exist. As I read the docs, I feel like my point still stands. Why making the component require a specific parent by binding upper layer, rather than passing required data using attr so that the component can be reused?